# bibtex output for @misc without year seems to depend on the label name of the misc item?

Tags: bibtex, revtex, bugs, labelling

I have a very strange bug using Latex with bibtex. I managed to solve it but I have no idea why it happened.

I am using `revtex4-2` on overleaf, with `apsrev4-2` bibliography style. The document I am writing is a scientific paper, and according to the journal guidelines footnotes should be handled as references, using the `@misc` type. The footnote will look like this in the `references.bib` file:

```
@misc{footnote_label,
  title = {Footnote text.}
  }
```

As they are footnotes, they obviously do not have a year, so I get a empty year warning, but the references look fine:

```
[1] Footnote text.
```

The issue is when I make two footnotes whose label names start the same, for example:

```
@misc{bla_abcdefg,
  title = {This is a footnote.}
  } 

@misc{bla_123456,
  title = {This is another footnote.}
  }
```

The references in the compiled pdf now have, for both these footnotes, an additional `().` behind the text, and the empty year warning for both these footnotes disappeared. They do still appear with the correct numbers. All other footnotes (and references to actual papers) are left unaltered. The output looks like this:

```
[1] This is a footnote. ().
[2] This is another footnote.  ().
```

This is exactly the same output as if I add the line `year = {}` to the `@misc` entry, including the disappearance of the year empty warning.

Changing the footnote labels such that only the first letter was the same or they started completely differently solved the issue but I do not understand why? Also because it is fine if they end the same (for example with the word footnote). Does bibtex internally use a reduced label that only takes the first few characters into account or something?

Comment: Don't add footnotes this way, add them normally with `\footnote` or pairing `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark`, as long as the right class options are passed to revtex (`footinbib`, but most journal-specific options will call this) then the footnotes will automatically end up in the bibliography.

Comment: As to whether there's a bug or something weird, I wouldn't be surprised if `misc` references without a year were unsupported by `apsrev4-2`, but it's a bit surprising if it is inconsistent like you describe.  Would you be able to add a minimal compilable tex document that can be compiled to reproduce the inconsistently handled `misc` entries as you describe?